# Count parent div of disabled inputs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
var inactive = $('div input[type="text"]:disabled');
var inactiv_col = ($(inactive[0]).length);
```

What i need is to count the parent div of disabled inputs.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, or what the problem is, without seeing the associated HTML. Also note that it sounds like using common class names instead of incremental ones would solve a lot of problems here.

Comment: I need to counts how many divs have disabled inputs and return the divs number. I know i didn't  explain well,

Comment: I have updated my questions and simplify it.

Comment: Can you show elements also?

Comment: That edit doesn't help. We need to see the HTML

Comment: Lets say i have 1 div with 4 inputs repeated 4 times (4 divs).. One of the divs might then have disabled inputs but the other 3 divs not. So i need the numbers of divs with disabled inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the above question, it seems like you want to count the number of the parents not childs. So you can try this

```js
$count=0;
$('.parent').each(function(){
if($(this).find('input[type="text"]:disabled').length !== 0){
$count++;
}
})
console.log($count)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
<input type="text" disabled>
<input type="text" disabled>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<input type="text" disabled>
</div>
<div class="parent">
<input type="text" disabled>
<input type="text" disabled>
<input type="text" disabled>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what i need. I need the number of parent div not the inputs its self.

Answer (score 1):

You are only counting the first item in the returned results - you need to simply get the length of the results.

```
var inactive = $('div input[type="text"]:disabled');
var inactiv_col = inactive.length;
```

Comment: that's exactly what i have, but i need numbers of div not numbers of disabled inputs.

Comment: This answer is not useful at all!

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:-

```
var count = 0;
        $('div').each(function(index, element) {            
            if($(this).find('input[type="text"]:disabled').length>0){                           
                count++;    
            }            
        });
        alert(count);
```

Comment: I need the number of divs, not the number of disabled fields. I have the same in my question.

Comment: Please try this code